# Why does tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier return null?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using xCode 4.2 to build an iPhone app.

I don't know why this statement `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` is null sometimes and not other times.  I am going to state two scenarios, the first one where cell is not null, and the second one where it is null.  Let me start with sample code shared by both scenarios from my WSCSessionTable which inherits UITableViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
     // we have null
    }
return cell;
}
```

**Scenario 1 - Cell is not null**

The cell is not null, and everything works fine when i set up my storyboard like so
[image: Navigation Controller to WSCSessionTable]

**Scenario 2 - Cell is null**

The cell is always null when i set up my storyboard like so:

[image: Activate WSCSession via button tap]

This is the event handler for the button that instantiates the table.

```
- (IBAction)goToSession:(id)sender
{
    wscAppDelegate *appDelegate = (wscAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    wscSessions *childView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sessionstable"];
//    wscSessions *childView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sessionstable"];
    childView._arrData = appDelegate._arrSession;
    childView._arrSpeaker = appDelegate._arrSpeaker;
    childView.title = @"SEssions";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES]; 
    }
```

Does anyone know why the cell is always null in scenario 2?  It's causing problems elsewhere in my code.

**Additional Info**
Two people i comments told me ot make sure the cell Identifier is set to "cell".  Here's a screen shot...is this correct?  It's like this in both scenario 1 and scenario 2.
[image]

Comment: Check the cell identifier in the storyboard scene that isn't working. It's not clear if you have two scenes or you are just rearranging your storyboard.

Comment: I am re-arranging my storyboard.  Cell identifier is there.

Comment: What @jrturton was saying is to make sure that in the second one, the cell identifier of the table view cell (which is set in the storyboard) is set to **Cell**.

Comment: @Inafziger - i added a screen shot in the additional info.  Did i set the cell identifer correctly?

Comment: Do you instantiate a cell object in your `if(cell == nil)` check?

Comment: @Barjavel - yes I do, but that's part of a more complicated question which I posted here which no one given me a working solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756791/nsbundle-mainbundle-gives-sigabrt-error